# Amazon S3/OpenStack Swift API skeleton

Tags: api, amazon-s3, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift

I would like to implement a cloud storage service with the same interface of OpenStack Swift or Amazon S3. In other words, my cloud storage service should expose the same API of the above-mentioned services but with a custom implementation. This way, a client will be able to interoperate with my service without changing its implementation.

I was wondering if there is an easier approach than manually implementing such interfaces starting from the documentation: http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html

For instance, it would be nice if there was a "skeleton" of OpenStack Swift or Amazon S3 APIs from which I can start implementing my service.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for:

- https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3
- https://github.com/scireum/s3ninja

These tools emulate most of Amazon S3 API. They are meant for development and test purposes but in my case I can use them as a starting point for implementing my cloud storage service.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has done this for you, try jcloud, it supports AWS S3 and swift: [Apache jclouds®](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Swift (Openstack object store ) which also supports S3 API
Take a look at the following link:
[http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-object-storage/admin/content/configuring-openstack-object-storage-with-s3_api.html](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/configuring-openstack-object-storage-with-s3_api.html)

This way you can work with openstack swift or Amazon S3

Answer (score -1):

Another option is libcloud, it is a python abstraction that supports a number of providers (including S3 and Swift):

https://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storage/index.html

http://libcloud.apache.org/

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for an enterprise / carrier grade object storage software solution, look at Cloudian http://www.cloudian.com.

Cloudian's software delivers a fully Amazon S3 compliant API, meaning that it delivers the broadest range of S3 feature coverage and 100% fidelity with the AWS S3 API.

The software comes with a Free 10TB license, so pretty much it is free up to 10TB of managed storage, after that it is reasonably priced. You can install the software in any x86 hardware running Linux.

Cloudian does not support the Swift API though.

[Disclaimer: I work for Cloudian]

Comment: Sounds as if the OP is looking to become your competition then, rather than opting in to your service ;S